# Django url dynamic link

Tags: django, conditional-operator

im using vuejs in django and i have this code

```
<form method="POST" :action="edit ? '{% url 'productoEdit' pk=request.path|slice:'19:21' %}' : '{% url 'productoCrud' %}'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

if the variabble `edit` is true `action` will be `{% url 'productoEdit' pk=request.path|slice:'19:21' %}` if is false `{% url 'productoCrud' %}`

the problem is that django gives me an error:
`Reverse for 'productoEdit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['user/productoEdit$', 'user/productoEdit/(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']`

this is my urls.py

```
path('productoEdit/<str:pk>', views.productoEdit, name="productoEdit"),
path('productoEdit', views.productoEdit, name="productoEdit")
```

as you can see the path productoEdit has 2 views, one with parameters and other without parameters.

this is my productoEdit in views.py

```
def productoEdit(request, pk=''): 
  producto = Producto.objects.get(id=pk)
  form = CreateProductForm(instance=producto)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateProductForm(request.POST, instance=producto)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      redirect('productoCrud')

  return render(request, 'productoCrud.html', {'form': form})
```

the problem ocurred when request.path is an empty string pk=''.

i tried using a ternay operator like this:
`pk=request.path|slice:'19:21' ? request.path|slice:'19:21' : None`

or
`pk=request.path|slice:'19:21'|yesno:'request.path|slice:'19:21',None'`

Django doesnt like my solutions xD, how can i resolve this problem?? thx so much for your help

**Problem solved***
**i did what  Abdul Aziz Barkat suggested**

```
{% if request.path|slice:'19:21' %}
     <form method="POST" action="{% url 'productoEdit' pk=request.path|slice:'19:21' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% else %}
     <form method="POST" action="{% url 'productoCrud' %}'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% endif %}
```

**i was using the js approach, now the error is gone, thx so much everyone**

Comment: Even Python doesn't have the ternary operator (`?:`) why do you think Django templates would have it? Why don't you simply use an if-else?

Answer (score 1):

Add if statement to check if PK exists before reversing a url.